# FileNotFoundException on getInputStream from GAE address

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine

I'm doing an Android app with an API with Python. The API is on a Google App Engine cloud and everything works fine when I tested it with Postman.

I'm trying to do a Login with a POST method. That method returns json with the user information I keep getting that error: FileNotFoundException

Here is some of my code:

```
try{
            String account = params[0].get(0);
            String password = params[0].get(1);

            URL url = new URL("http", WEB_SERVICE_URL, PORT, REST_LOGIN);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);


            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");


            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.serialJsonLogin(nomCompte, motPasse);


            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(),"UTF-8");
            osw.write(json.toString());
            osw.flush();
            String body = readStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            osw.close();




            Log.i(TAG, "Return : " + body);

            user = jsonParser.deserializeJsonUser(body);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            mException = e;
        }finally {
            if (mHttpURLConnection != null) {
                mHttpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return user;
```

At: String body = readStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()); I'm getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.2.2:8080/login

My readStream method is fine, I tested it. If I look in my Google App Engine logs, I can see that there is no 404, or anything wrong. If I find the user I get a 201 if not a 403. So even if the error says FileNotFound, I see status code which means that actually the URL is right.

**UPDATE:** My API was giving me a 201 and getInputStream apparently doesn't work on 201 status. Changed my return status to 200 in my API and it works fine.